# programmatically segued navigation link reverts after sheet is displayed

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am having an issue where a programatically fired navigation link reverts to the root view after a sheet is called in the child view.

I am using the isActive method to call the child view after an async process. It seems that once the sheet is called (FilterView) the isActive variable (showResults) reverts to false.

Here's a video of the issue:

https://ibb.co/sKgbm4s

Root view variables:

```
@EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
@State private var findings : [DDxFinding]
@State private var comorbids : [Comorbid]
@State private var showSheet = false
@State private var ageType : AgeType = .year
@State private var acuity : Acuity = .any
@State private var age : String = ""
@State private var sex : Sex = .any
@State private var degree : Degree = .two
let generator : DDxGenerator
let progressor : DDxProgress
@State private var progress : Float = 0
@State private var cancel : Bool = false
@State private var showResults : Bool = false
@State private var solutions : [Solution]?

init(findings: [DDxFinding] = [], comorbids : [Comorbid] = []) {
    _findings = State(initialValue: findings)
    _comorbids = State(initialValue: comorbids)
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderHeight = -1
    
    generator = DDxGenerator(dbType: .sqlite)
    progressor = DDxProgress()
    generator.progressDelegate = progressor

}

var body: some View {
```

Root view calling code:

```
Section(footer:  NavigationLink(destination: NavigationLazyView(DDxResultView(solutions: solutions)), isActive: $showResults) {
        }.hidden()) {
            let symps = findings.map {DdxFinding(id: $0.id, target: $0.targetted.intValue, root: $0.name)}
            let comorbs = comorbids.map {DdxFinding(id: $0.id, root: $0.name)}
            let data = DDxData(sex: sex.toInt, acuity: acuity.toInt, ageType: ageType.toInt, age: Int(age) ?? -1, degree: degree.toInt, symps: symps, comorbids: comorbs)
            Button("Submit") {
                if symps.isEmpty {
                    self.userSettings.showsAlert = true
                    self.userSettings.alertTitle = Text("Input atleast one finding.")
                    return
                }
                self.userSettings.showsAlert2 = true
                cancel = false
                progress = 0
                self.userSettings.alert2Body = AnyView(CustomProgressView(progress: $progress, cancel: $cancel))
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    do {
                        solutions = try generator.generateDDx(improvedData: data, db: database,
                            alertCode: { progress in
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.progress = progress
                                }
                            }, cancelCode: {
                                return cancel
                            })
                    } catch {
                        solutions = nil
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if !cancel {
                            self.showResults = true
                        }
                        self.userSettings.showsAlert2 = false
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center).foregroundColor(.blue).font(.headline)
        }
    }
    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```

Child view sheet code:

```
struct DDxResultView: View {

var solutions : [Solution]?
@ObservedObject var ddxObject : DDxObject
@State private var showingFilter = false

init(solutions: [Solution]?) {
    self.ddxObject = DDxObject(solutions: solutions)
    self.solutions = solutions
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderHeight = -1
}


var body: some View {
    
    let data = self.ddxObject.sectionData

    if solutions == nil {
        errorView(.general)
    } else {
        List {
            ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Section(header: Text(data[index].header)) {
                    ForEach(data[index].rows.indices, id: \.self) { index2 in
                        
                        ResultRowView(data: $ddxObject.sectionData[index].rows[index2])
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingFilter) {
            VinFilterView(vinSelections: $ddxObject.vinSelections, showingFilter: $showingFilter)
        }
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: agree with jnpdx, would like to experiment for ourselves

Comment: I will attempt to make something more succinct! Thanks.